# Padding zeroes in non-Text lists

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of numbers that have 3 digits after the dash (FL-100), but in the list are numbers that are formatted with only 2 digits after the dash (AR-12). They all need leading zeroes in order to have 3 digits after the dash. I have tried the TEXT function with no luck because Excel isn't recognizing these as text for some reason. Does anyone have any suggestions to add a leading zero ONLY to the figures with 2 digits after the dash, in a list including figures that are already formatted properly with 3 digits? A sample of the list is attached.

```
FL-05 

FL-08 


FL-100

FL-101

FL-102

FL-103

FL-104
```

Thanks in advance, folks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,3) & TEXT(--MID(A1,4,9999),"000")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: Dude, this is awesome! Works like a charm! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

If you already have the numbers and the 'FL-' text  munched together, you need to split them first, the formula would be `=VALUE(MID(cell,4,99))`; if they are separately accessible already, you can skip that step.

Next step is to format them for three digits: `=TEXT(cell,"000")`.

Third is concatenating the two pieces back together with `&`.

All together: `=LEFT(cell,3)&TEXT(VALUE(MID(cell,4,99)),"000")`